# A description of technology during Kalki's birth

Tags: vishnu, time, kalki, kalki-purana

As humans have evolved over the ages, so has their technology. This signifies that when Kalki is born, the technology will have significantly developed and there will be numerous things which are not available at present.

**Are there any future technologies mentioned which are not available today?**

Comment: "Are there any future technologies mentioned which are not available today?" Would he rishis predict something which was not available at that time? Why do you think?

Comment: @Sarvabhouma If a rishi can see a DevatA, as happens for all the mantras, why can't a rishi foresee technological advances?

Comment: @Pratimaputra Why should they speak of the technology in a purana? I mean what is the need. People will use flying cars, 5G mobile phones etc., is this the purpose of a purana?

Comment: Yes. The white horse with wings is a metaphor for an advanced vehicle that can fly and cross oceans in almost an instant. Moreover, 1,of Kalki's wifes has very advanced drones surrounding her (what sounds like a) castle. I think also have seen references towards floating buildings but I have to check.

Comment: "why can't a rishi foresee technological advances". Because my friend this is all just a story/fairy tale.